# Is Tannu Rabbanan in the Gemara a Tannaic or Amoraic teaching?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli

In the Gemara, the phrase תנו רבנן (*Tanna Rabbanan*) introduces various sorts of teachings. Are these teachings exclusively Tannaic or Amoraic in source?

Answer (score 3):

These sources are generally Tannaic in nature. They usually introduce what my Gemara Rebbe in yeshiva referred to as "well-known *beraitot*".

The following is a quote from the Wikipedia article about [beraitot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraita)

> Here, a teaching from the Baraita is usually introduced by the Aramaic word "*Tanya*" ("It was orally taught") or by "*Tanu Rabanan*" ("*Our Rabbis* have orally taught"), whereas "*Tnan*" ("We have orally taught") introduces quotations from the Mishna.

As @DoubleAA rightly pointed out in the comments, like any "rule" there are exceptions. *Tannu Rabanan* is definitely used occasionally to quote mishnas and I believe it is even occasionally used to quote amoraic discussions.

Comment: I upvoted, but will wait for a linkable source before accepting.

Comment: @hugh Answer updated

Comment: Hebrew wikipedia says: Braisa or Tosefta https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%92%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99

Comment: @Hugh The _Tosefta_ is made up of _beraitot_.

Comment: well that is like saying the Mishna is made up of beraitot ;)

Comment: @Hugh No it's not... The Mishna isn't made up of beraitot. It's made up of mishnayot.

Comment: the tosefta is a specific group of tannaic teachings that didn't make it into the mishna, but have more weight than a braisa

Comment: @Hugh The Tosefta is a collection of beraitot which are weightier than other beraitot.

Comment: @Hugh Beraita is the generic name for Tannaic teaching that didn't make it into the Mishna. The Tosefta is a collection of some of those beraitot.

Comment: @Hugh See the [Wikipedia page Baraita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraita): "The main collections of Baraita are the Tosefta, and the Halakhic Midrashim (Mekhilta, Sifra and Sifre)."

Comment: ah okay, I thought the baraita was tanaaic teachings not in the mishna or tosefta :)